# Xamarin Convert imageUrl to imagesource via webclient Auto Rotaion Bug

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I convert imageUrl to imagesource via webclient.

Here is my Code

```
 public static async Task<ImageSource> MakeImageSource(string url)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                byte[] byteArray = null;

                byteArray = webClient.DownloadData(url);

                if (byteArray != null)
                    return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArray));

            }

            return "";
        }
```

But when I convert a horizontally long image, it rotates by 90.

This is the xaml code that uses the image source.

I have binding an imageSource to a 'ProfileImage'.

```
                        <Grid>
                            <Frame  WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" Padding="0" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="20" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Source="profile_2"/>
                                    <Image WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Source="{Binding ProfileImage}"/>
                                </Grid>
                                
                            </Frame>
                            <Frame WidthRequest="15" HeightRequest="15" CornerRadius="7.5" Padding="1" HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="White" IsClippedToBounds="True"
                                   VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                <Frame.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="{Binding UserLoginPlatform}" Value="001">
                                        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Frame.Triggers>
                                <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding UserLoginPlatform}" IsVisible="true"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
```

what's the problem

Comment: is there a reason you don't use the url directly as the ImageSource?

Comment: There’s nothing obvious in that code that would or could rotate by 90 degrees. Therefore, you need to debug - find out exactly where this rotated image is coming from. Maybe its the uri itself. Maybe its code you haven’t shown - what xaml surrounds the snippet in question? Start over. Write simplest possible page to test getting image from that uri. BTW, HTTPClient is preferred over WebClient. Though as Jason says, you might not need either here.

Comment: I solved it using HTTPClient, thanks.